# How to identify and hide/remove an element from a WordPress page

Tags: posts, themes, templates, page-template

I created my first WordPress website using Elementor and an all-in-one theme called Webify.

Since I am new to WordPress and to website design, I've imported a demo website that comes with the Webify theme and I am editing based on that import.

I noticed that some pages on my site have this top 'stripe' with a background image and some text on the page name and location.

For example, the blog page has this horizontal stripe, with a red background image, and the text ***Blog*** on the left-hand side and ***Home / Blog*** on the right-hand side:

[image: blog page]

Do you see it? Right under the logo and the header menu? I want to remove this horizontal stripe!
The thing is, I can't find how. As far as I can tell, it's not an Elementor element, because when I edit the page in Elementor I can't interact with it. I also didn't find how to remove it from the WP Customize tool.

I do have pages on my site that don't have this top horizontal stripe, like this one:

[image]

Let's call this kind of page "Good Page"

I can edit a good page to create the beautiful page I want:

[image]

but whenever I try to create a new page I get a page with this horizontal stripe. I tried creating a new page directly from WP, from Elementor, I tried using a good page and creating an Elementor template from it and then importing the template to a new page, and even tried cloning a good page, using [this WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/copy-delete-posts/) but in all these attempts, the new page I got had that stripe );

Looking at the page attributes for both a good page and a new page I created, I couldn't figure out any attribues that were controling this horizontal stripe.

I would be grateful for some help on on to remove this horizontal stripe!

In adddition, I would also love some debugging pointers on how to go about identifying an element such as this one, and then hide it in the CSS.

Thank you so much for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the element you are seeing can not be edited in Elementor, then this is part of the theme template. You should consider looking directly at the theme page template you are using on this page to solve.

Nether the less, as per your question you can remove this globally using css. In your browser you can Inspect Element, select this div element and use the selector to add the following code in your custom css.

```
 .yourexampleselector {
    
    Display: none;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As P.Sav said, it comes from your theme. You install the "Show current template" extension for wordpress which will show you for a page which template you are on and then you can find out which template file it is from.

And if you can't do it, you can always look at the classes that wordpress adds in each page that are in the body tag, they allow the CSS properties to be applied on a page-by-page basis.
[image]

You can also add custom css code via élementor but I find this solution a little less clean because we quickly forget where we placed the code.

[image]